# Powerpivot Dax- Calculate number of Hours after a fixed time

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a list of times in a column [Logtime]:

```
11:45:44PM
07:05:05PM
```

I'd like to create a measure that returns the total number of hours after 6:30PM. So given the above times:

```
5.5
0.58
```

HoursAfter:=[logtime] -6:30PM doesn't work.

Hour[logtime] - hour(18.5) also doesn't work

EDIT:
timevalue([logtime]) - timevalue("05:00:00") works but it returns a datetime ala
12/30/1899 5:17:16PM

I need to convert the time `5:17:16` into decimal hours i.e. `5.26`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a slightly more elegant way, but I was able to create a calculated column that does what you want as follows,

```
HoursAfter = DATEDIFF(TIMEVALUE("6:30 PM"), Times[LogTime], SECOND) / 3600
```

This takes the time difference between 6:30 PM and your `LogTime` in units of seconds and then converts it to hours by dividing by 60*60 = 3600.

**Edit:** A simpler formula can be written as follows,

```
HoursAfter = 24 * (Times[LogTime] - TIMEVALUE("6:30 PM"))
```

(Multiply by 24 since the datetime values are stored in units of days.)

Answer (score 0):

timevalue([logtime]) - timevalue("05:00:00")